# I get garbage value on this jagged array

Tags: oop, multidimensional-array, visual-c++, jagged-arrays

I get garbage value on this jagged array, that takes input size from another array's last value which must be -111(if not ten add one index to put in -111).
i know i have missed some cout statements but dont know why i get garbage vals

'''

```
int jaggedArr(int** arr2, int r, int c)
{
    int* numbers = nullptr;
    numbers = new int[r]; /// array to store no of columns
    int** jagArr = new int* [r];   /// jagged array

    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        int tempNum;
        for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {                //store size of cols in arr4 to put int new array (arr3)
            if (arr2[i][j] == -111)
            {
                tempNum = j;
                numbers[i] = tempNum;//if -111 is present then dont change size just copy
            }
            else if (arr2[i][j] != -111)
            {
                tempNum = j + 1;
                numbers[i] =tempNum;//else  if -111 is not present then dont change size just copy
            }
        tempNum = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        jagArr[i] = new int[numbers[i]];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)//remove 10
        {
            jagArr[i] = new int[numbers[i]];
        }
    }
    cout << "Showing all the Inputed data in a matrix form" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i]; j++) 
        {
            //if (jagArr[i][j] >= 0 && jagArr[i][j] <= 9)
            //{
            //  cout << jagArr[i][j] << "   |";
            //}
            //else if (jagArr[i][j] == -111)
            //{
            //  cout << jagArr[i][j] << "|";
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //  cout << jagArr[i][j] << "  |";
            //}
            cout << jagArr[i][j];
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return **arr2;
}
'''
```

Comment: The loop that uses `tempNum` is pointless. It's equivalent to `numbers[i] = arr2[i][c-1] == -111 ? c-1 : c;` . That is, `numbers[i]` is always set to either `c` or `c-1`, depending on whether the last element in `arr2[i]` array is -111. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but probably not this.

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) { jagArr[i] = new int[numbers[i]]; }` This makes no sense at all. You are allocating 10 blocks of memory, and assign each in turn to the same variable, thereby leaking nine out of ten. Considering that `jagArr[i]` was already pointing to `new int[numbers[i]]` allocated earlier, you are exactly where you started, plus a bunch of leaked memory.

Comment: `cout << jagArr[i][j]` You never actually assigned any values to elements of `jagArr`. Here you are printing random garbage that just happens to sit in uninitialized memory. Did you mean to have `jagArr[i][j] = arr2[i][j]` in there somewhere?